# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883 throw err;

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code:

```
const fs= require("fs");
const text=fs.readFileSync("dele.txt","utf-8");
console.log(text);
```

Here is the error in terminal:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\programs\web development\tut64.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)       
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is certainly not the cause of the problem. Your script fails to load a module located at `D:\programs\web development\tut64.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you are asking for `fs` module.

Try to run `npm install fs` in your console and be sure that you are running the command in your root folder.